# How do I change the parameter of a specific widget through the provider?

Tags: flutter

I have three CustomButtons, under some condition, I want to change the first button from the list. The question is how to identify a button by name or something like that? Is there any way to bind the Provider to a specific button, so that the buttons are the same (CustomButton), but you can change it by changing the parameter of the specific

Comment: Can you share the sample code

Comment: ```Code example:`

Column(
    children: [
        CustomButton(title: "First button"),
        CustomButton(title: "Second button")
    ]
)```

Comment: Did you built the CustomButton widget or trying to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a `CustomButton` widget and pass the arguments.

I have used `InkWell` widget which has `onTop` property.
`onTap()` function is used in the below example, which perform action specific to the button, so every time I reuse the `CustomButton` widget so I can specify the action.

If you want to use different operations such as `onPressed()` or `onHover()` - you can build the `CustomButton` widget using `ElevatedButton` widget.

Hope this help!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorSchemeSeed: Colors.indigo,
        useMaterial3: true,
        brightness: Brightness.light,
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        colorSchemeSeed: Colors.blue,
        useMaterial3: true,
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Example App'),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children:[
            CustomButton(
              iconData: Icons.hail,
              title: 'Baggage Claim',
              onTap: () {
                print('Are you sure you want claim your baggage?');
              },
            ),
            Divider(),
            CustomButton(
              iconData: Icons.exit_to_app,
              title: 'Exit'
            ),
          ]
        )
      )
    );
  }
}

class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.iconData,
    this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final IconData iconData;
  final String title;
  final Function()? onTap;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Material(
        elevation: 8.0,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: onTap,
          child: Container(
            height: 50.0,
            width: 200.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 50.0,
                  width: 40.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.deepPurple,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                  ),
                  child: Icon(
                    iconData,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    title,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15,
                        color: Colors.purple,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to clarify, I meant instead of "Under some condition change parameter", that when a function is called - not by clicking, but for example from a timer, a function will be called that will change the parameter. In my case from CustomButton, I need to call the _setCountMessages(4) function.

Comment: Use Provider.of<type>() to fetch the value we need from up the tree, if you share piece of code, i would try  to add the missing piece